# html2pdf = $html2pdf->WriteHTML($VARIABLE); line causing problems

Tags: php, html2pdf

I have a form that takes user input, posts to itself and stores my php code into a string variable and saves that string data to a .html file on my server.  I'd like to do away with the .html file and instead save to .pdf with html2pdf but I'm running into an issue.

I have the following code in my php file:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','Letter','en');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($current);
$html2pdf->Output('/var/www/Inspection/Quote/exemple.pdf');
```

When I comment out the third line "$html2pdf->WriteHTML($current);" I get an error of "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file".

When I comment out the third and fourth lines the rest of my page carries out without issue. . . I just don't get my .pdf.

I've seen some posts regarding flushing out something right before the write line but none of them were clear enough for me to work through.

Also, if I use a much simplified code I can generate the pdf properly. . . I'm lost as to why this is possible.

Here is what works:

```
$content = "
<page>
<h1>Exemple d'utilisation</h1>
<br>
Ceci est un <b>exemple d'utilisation</b>
de <a href='http://html2pdf.fr/'>HTML2PDF</a>.<br>
</page>";

 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
```

*** EDIT ***
$current =

```
 <br><div align="center"><H1><center>Sales Order: <font color="red" style="bold"> 1 3
    </font></center></h1>
    </div>
    <hr width="85%">
    <table width="800" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="50%" align="center">
    <table frame="border">
    <th bgcolor="cccccc" colspan="2" align="center">General Order Information</th>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Order Num:</td>
        <td width="60%">1</td>
    </tr>   
        <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Order Rev:</td>
        <td width="20%">3</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Quote Num:</td>
        <td width="20%">1</td>
    </tr>       
        <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Order Date:</td>
        <td width="60%">1970-01-01</td>
    </tr>           
        <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Customer Name:</td>
        <td width="60%">1</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Customer Buyer:</td>
        <td width="60%">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Sold By:</td>
        <td width="60%">ED </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Sales Rep:</td>
        <td width="60%">DR</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width="40%">Prog Mgr:</td>
        <td width="60%">VJ</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <!-- Start of Shipping Data -->
    <td valign="top" width="50%">
    <table align="center" frame="Border">
    <th bgcolor="cccccc" colspan="2" align="center">Shipping Information</th>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" >Terms:</td>
    <td align="left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" >FOB:</td>
    <td align="left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" >Shipping Co:</td>
    <td align="left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Ship Acct Num:</td>
    <td align="left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">Shipping Method:</td>
    <td align="left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center" valign="top">Order Comments:</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center" width="40%">Cust SO Upload:</td>
        <td width="60%">The file 1-1-3.jpg has been uploaded, and Quote 1 has been added to the Quote directory </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr width="85%">  <table align="center" width="85%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"             frame="border" rules="all">
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Line</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Cust PN / Rev</td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>PN / Rev</td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Description</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Qty</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>UOM</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Sale Price</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Line Total</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Required Date</h5></td>
    <td bgcolor="cccccc" align="center"><h5>Program</h5></td>
    </tr>  <tr>
    <td width="3px" valign="top" align="center">
    1 </td> <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1 - 1
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1 - 1
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1.00
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1.00
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1970-01-01
    </td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="center">
    1
    </td>
    </tr> <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="10" bgcolor="cccccc">
    <b>The Order Total is 1.00</b>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

wkhtmltopdf is something I'd like to stay away from as it requires an x-server. . . something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually have a variable `$current`? In your test example you use `$content`.

Comment: And you didn't actually include your error message.

Comment: Can we see the contents of the `$current` variable?

Comment: I do have a variable $current... It is somewhat lengthy.  I've added to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You should review all the php script which creates the PDF, and then review that there is not any kind of "spare row" or white line, before your

```
<?php
```

tag. 
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You have to be really careful to not output (aka render) anything before you wrote your PDF.

The error message "I get an error of "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file" is usually due to the fact that you have echoed something before you wrote your PDF.

The thing you noted about other people saying something about "flushing something" has to do with "output buffering" - and that is a technique you should absolutely use with html2pdf/TCPDF.

Output buffering works as follows:

```
ob_start() //starts output buffering
echo "<p>String you want to write to your PDF</p>";
$stringForPdf = ob_get_contents(); // this now contains the the above string
ob_end_clean(); // close and clean the output buffer.
html2pdf->WriteHtml($stringForPdf);
```

You can refer to the full documentation here: [Output Buffering Control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Furthermore, make sure you have no closing PHP tag: ?> in your PHP files, as every following whitespace will be output.

If you supply more of the code befor and after your snipped, I might be able to analyze this further.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use WKHTMLTOPDF but without having to install it, you could use [Sprint PDF](http://www.sprintpdf.com). It's an online service to convert HTML to PDF and does so via RESTful API.

Comment: and when sprintpdf decides to shut down, your project is dead